# Should I version control manage.py in Django?

Tags: django

Using this command:

```
django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

The following directory structure is generated:

```
mysite/
    manage.py
    mysite/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
```

Should I version control `manage.py` which contains:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', '[REDACTED].settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Looking at the contents of the file, I don't think I need to, but just to be sure, I'm asking you lovely people :)

Comment: You don't need to, but you make it harder to "run" your project, and the file is relatively small, so I do not see much reasons why not to include it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should just add it to version control.  You don't need to, but there's **no reason you shouldn't** version it.

Is it a part of your application: Yes, other developers need to use manage.py, so perhaps it should be left in version control so everyone is always using the same manage.py file.

Could manage.py change over time: Yes, while most people might not modify manage.py, it *can* be modified if you ever feel a need to so it should probably be versioned.

Does it contain any secrets or credentials: No, because there are no secrets it in, there's no reason not to version it.